# Stop page life cycle execution after response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I am having a base class which implements some basic authentication for all the pages in the application.

```
public class BasePage : Page
{

    public void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsUserValid())
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }


}

public class AuthenticatedUser : BasePage
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Databind();
        }
    }
}
```

How to stop page life cycle for AuthenticatedUser, if the user is invalid?

Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Response.Redirect will absolutely stop the page lifecycle execution. If you did NOT want it to stop, you would add a parameter value of `false` after the redirect target.

Maybe I'm not clear on what you're asking, if you wanted to stop without a redirect then use `Response.End()`.

Answer (score -1):

in Response.Redirect you can set a boolean:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
```

Using method in this mode, the page lifecyce is stopped when method is called.(false is endResponse boolean)

Comment: It's the other way around, the response is ended by default. This would cause it not to be stopped. Technically you're supposed to do it this way to avoid errors in your output window, but what a pain, since then you have to handle that condition for the rest of your page.